# Maximum gas estimate

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, evm, gas-estimate, gas-refund

`eth_estimateGas` provides estimated final gas consumed by transaction and accounts for gas refund in the end of transaction. However, is there a way to estimate **maximum** gas the transaction may consume during execution, omitting the refunds?